# Make jasmine test wait until dependent method call's promise is resolved

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have to test a void method which has a dependent method call that returns a promise and I can't mock that call as it is made on a local object created inside the tested method.

Is there a way to make jasmine expect calls to wait until the promise is resolved? I tried using `$rootScope.$digest()` but it is not ensuring that the dependent call's promise is resolved.

**EDIT:** Adding sample code

```
module.service('serviceToBeTested', ['$rootScope', 'someOtherService',
  function($rootScope, someOtherService) {
    var thirdPartyLib;

    function fnToBeTested() {
      //some validations and filtering on rootScope variable to build input for processing

      thirdPartyLib = new ThirdPartyLib(); //this is not an angular service

      var anotherFunction = function() {
        //some hook functions that will be triggered by the third party library
      }

      // anotherFunction  is set into thirdPartyLib so that hook functions will be triggered

      thirdPartyLib.start().then(funtion() {
        thirdPartyLib.someThing.load(); //this load will trigger one hook function
      }
    }
  }]);
```

What I need to verify is that, upon invoking `fnToBeTested()`, a particular logic inside a hook function is executed (for that the control has to go inside the `then` part of `thirdPartyLib.start()`).

Actually this gets executed but only after the expect statements in the spec are executed.

And my spec file is almost like this:

```
  it('should do this and this', function() {
    // some initialization
    serviceToBeTested.fnToBeTested();
    $rootScope.$digest();
    //expect statements
  });
```

**EDIT 2: Adding details on trial made as Andrew suggested below and adding clarity on how instance is created**

ThirtPartyLib is instantiated inside main source as:

```
var theLib = require('theLib');
...............................
thirdPartyLib = new theLib.ThirdPartyLib();
```

And in spec, I created a var just like this and spied prototype as below:

```
var theLib = require('theLib');
................................
spyOn(theLib.ThirtPartyLib.prototype, 'start').and.callFake(.....);
```

But the fake function is not reached. When I check `theLib.ThirtPartyLib.prototype` in spec during debug, it lists the SpyStrategy while checking `theLib.ThirtPartyLib.prototype` in main source, it doesn't list that.

Comment: The only way to do this is to somehow gain access to that promise. You need to refactor your method to expose the promise. Can you please add some code? We need to know what you are trying to test.

Comment: Thanks for the response @AndrewEisenberg. I have added some sample code. I can't modify the code and the method returning the promise is not part of an angular service etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to test this with some clever use of mocking. In your `beforeEach` block, you can do something like this:

```
let promise; // declare this outside of your beforeEach so you have access to it in the specs

promise = $q.resolve();  // assign promise to 
spyOn(ThirdPartyLib.prototype, 'start').and.returnValue(promise);
```

And then in your test, you now have access to the promise returned by start.

Comment: Will this spy work on the instance created using new operator? It seems like the actual method is called, when I tried this way.

Comment: Why don't you try it. :) It works because of how prototypal inheritance is implemented. the function `new ThirdPartyLib().start` is the same as `ThirdPartyLib.prototype.start`.

Comment: I had tried it. But it was still going to the actual implementation (probably due to the way I tried or because the sample code I added doesn't convey the whole form of the service). I'm new to UI and UI testing. Trying again.

Comment: I had seen somewhere else about spying on the constructor itself and had tried that also thinking that I could control the third party lib behaviour that way. But that too didn't work.

Comment: One more thing to add. Not sure if that makes any change. The ThirtPartyLib is brought into main source using require call of a module. Please check the edit.